# При обновлении сайта выдает `alert`

Tags: javascript, html, css, обработка-ошибок

При обновлении или загрузке сайта, выдает `alert`.

Как его убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не копировать бездумно JS.

Answer (score 9):

Давайте его искать:

- Открываем исходный код страницы - правой кнопкой, <kbd>Просмотр кода страницы</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> - ищем `alert(` - не находим
- Смотрим, какие внешние скрипты подключаются
  Это можно сделать вручную, либо <kbd>F12</kbd>-<kbd>Sources</kbd>-<kbd>js</kbd>
- Видим в **Maine_Js.js** на строке `219`:
  `alert( 'Текущая прокрутка сверху: ' + window.pageYOffset );`

Уберите его из этого файла на сервере.

Comment: Если бы вы расскажете, каким образом вы это обнаружили - ответ будет гораздо полезнее.

Comment: Открыл исходный код страницы, и не обнаружив через CTRL+F функции alert() - нашел внешний файл скрипта который подключается, и в нем нашел этот алерт.

Comment: Не хорошо воровать ответы.

Comment: @Vadizar, кто чего воровал? Прекратите вандализм

Comment: @vp_arth вы скопировали мой ответ и вставили его сюда. Зачем?

Comment: @Vadizar, я запросил у пользователя информацию, а потом (отформатировав) перенёс её в ответ. Ваш ответ я вообще никак не использовал, честное слово. Да и разные они эти ответы.

Comment: @user190134 про какой сайт идет речь?

Comment: @Vadizar на скрине в вопросе видно в алерте сайт

Answer (score 1):

**Если проект развернут локально:**

1. Открываем IDE
2. <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> по проекту
3. Вводим в диалоговое окно `alert`
4. Находим, где вызывается это диалоговое окно и удаляем.

**Если проект не развернут локально:**

1. Инспектируем подключение скриптов на сайте <kbd>F12</kbd>-<kbd>Sources</kbd>-<kbd>js</kbd>. Или же ищем прямо на хостинге.
2. Находим `alert` и убираем его. Если не находим в JS, пробуем искать прямо в разметке.

**Если подключаются внешние скрипты:**

Может быть, что `alert` вызывается из внешней библиотеки, которую вы подключаете через CDN. Тогда советовал бы скопировать её к себе на сервер и откорректировать согласно рекомендациям выше. Или же вообще задаться вопросом - а нужна ли она вам?